# error in crawler method by using firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I got below error

```
 python niada.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "niada.py", line 10, in <module>
    status, response = http.request('http://www.niada.com/member_directory.php?te_mode=map_view')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1129, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/httplib2/__init__.py", line 901, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/httplib2/__init__.py", line 887, in _conn_request
    content = _decompressContent(response, content)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/httplib2/__init__.py", line 358, in _decompressContent
    raise FailedToDecompressContent(_("Content purported to be compressed with %s but failed to decompress.") % response.get('content-encoding'), response, content)
httplib2.FailedToDecompressContent: Content purported to be compressed with gzip but failed to decompress.
```

I unable to clear this error,my python.How can be solved 
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Read the error, it's telling you that it can't decompress a file which is supposed to be a zip.  This most likely means that either the file is corrupt, or it's not actually a zip file.  Find the file in question and see if you can decompress it using gzip or similar. If gzip doesn't like it either then it looks like the file is the problem.

As to how it can be fixed I can't tell you much going on the information you've given. Without  giving some detail about the context of the problem and what you're actually trying to do then nobody's going to be able to help you.  I advise that you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to find out how to ask a question in such a way that people will be happy and able to answer.